# Выбрать выделенный текст из любого элемента `html` (Не только из инпутов)

Tags: javascript, html

Допустим у нас есть какие то параграфы.

```
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
<p>when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a</p>
```

И мышкой я выбрал какую то часть текста из любого из них. Так вот как мне после этого или на стадии выборки получить выбранный текст. А еще лучше и контейнер этого текста то же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Интересно я думал `window.getSelection()` только для инпутов. Но в нем выбирается все что мышкой выделить. И вот ответ был у меня под носом))).

```js
function getSelectionText(){
  var text = "";
  text = window.getSelection().toString();
  return text;
}
document.onmouseup = document.onkeyup = document.onselectionchange = function() {
  document.getElementById("sel").value = getSelectionText();
};
```

```html
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
<p>Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
<p>when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a</p>
<textarea id="sel" rows="6" cols="50"></textarea>
```

Comment: возможно  можно и без .toString() и window убрать

Comment: Без `.toString()` нет. Можете пробивать и здесь в сниппете код без него.

Comment: у меня всё работает без тустринг и если подмешивать к выводу нечего не надо, можно сразу передавать метод getSelection() в валую